# How to split cell into sepatare rows and find minial summary value

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following dataset:

```
Movies : moviename, genre1, genre2, genre3 ..... genre19
```

(All the genres above have values 0 or 1, 1 indicates that the movie is of that genre)
Now i want to find which movie(s) has least genre?

I tried the below Pig script:

```
items = load 'path' using PigStorage('|') as (mName:chararray,g1:int,g2:int,g3:int,g4:int,g5:int,g6:int,g7:int,g8:int,g9:int,g10:int,g11:int,g12:int,g13:int,g14:int,g15:int,g16:int,g17:int,g18:int,g19:int);

sumGenre = foreach items generate mName, g1+g2+g3+g4+g5+g6+g7+g8+g9+g10+g11+g12+g13+g14+g15+g16+g17+g18+g19 as sumOfGenres;

groupAll = group sumGenre All;
```

In the next step by using MIN(sumGenre.sumofGenres), i can get a genre which is the MIN value , but what am looking for is to get a moviename which has the least no. of genres, alongside the number of genres of that movie.

Can someone please help?
1. I want to know is there any other easy way to get the sum of g1+g2+...g19?
2. Also the output : movie(s) that has the least genre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `groupAll`

```
r1 = minGenre = foreach groupAll generate MIN(sumGenre.sumOfGenres) as minG;
```

do left outer join between `r1` by `minG` with `sumGenre` by `sumOfGenres`;

to get the list of movies having least genre..

Hope this will help..

for dynamic row field sum u can use UDF like this..

```
public class DynRowSum  extends EvalFunc<Integer> 
{
public Integer  exec(Tuple v) throws IOException
{
List<Object>  olist  =  v.getAll();
int sum = 0;
int cnt=0;
for( Object o : olist){
   cnt++;
   if (cnt!=1) {
                int val= (Integer)o;
                sum = sum + val;
   }
}
return new Integer(sum);
}

}
```

In pig update the script like this..

```
grunt>sumGenre = foreach items generate mName,DynRowSum(*) as sumOfGenres;
```

Advantage here you will get if genre increase or decrease code will remain same..

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is working but i took the inner join with the same logic as yours. Thanks again!!!  Also could you please suggest me if (g1+g2+g3..g19) is a good way of coding or shall i go for a UDF?

Comment: @ValarMorghulis g1+g2+g3..g19 is definitly a bad appoach as you could have new columns or old columns to be removed

Comment: @Alex : thanks for the reply, could you tell me is there any built in function to perform such a huge sum of many columns or shall i use UDFs?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = LOAD 'path';
b = FOREACH a generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0, '\\|'));
c = FOREACH b generate $0 as movie, FLATTEN(TOBAG(*)) as genre;
d = FILTER c BY movie!=genre;
e = GROUP d BY $0;
f = FOREACH e GENERATE group, SUM(d);
i = ORDER f BY $1;
j = LIMIT i 1;
```

Comment: Hi @Alex: Could you please explain what is your logic at step 2 and 3. I did not get those steps...

Comment: @ValarMorghulis It reverts your tuple from: {movie,g1,g2,g3 .. gn} to {movie,movie},{movie,g1},{movie,g2},{movie,g3},...,{movie,gn}. Next step will remove {movie,movie}. it is an answer to your first question, so that you can have a dynamic number of genres and you will not have to modify your query each time the number of genres changes.